# Deducing the value of one parameter

Tags: algebras

I'm working with Javascript and I need some help because I'm not great at math. I have the following code:

```
let x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * x0 
  + 3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * x1
  + 3 * (1 - t) * t * t * x2 
  + t * t * t * x3;
```

I know the values of `x`, `x0`, `x1`, `x2` and `x3`.  Is it possible to deduce the value of `t`?

Comment: Do you know Cardano's method to solve third degree equation.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't

Comment: Google it and you will get an idea.

Comment: First you should expand out the expression so it has the following form: $at^3 + bt^2 + ct  + (d-x) = 0$, where $a,b,c,d$ will be functions of $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$. Then you can use Cardano's method. You can implement it yourself, but you may even be able to find template code online or a built in library in JS.